# Need explanation on how the select queries are handled by mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have no issues running a select query on mongoS, in a sharded environment, but my question is:

If have a 2 shard server setup and run a `find` query via application layer, which part of the sharded environment is reponsible for executing the query?

I am not able to see any change in any of instance's consoles and also no new process is created. I tested this by executing 3000 `find` queries on a locally implemented sharding setup.

Can anybody explain where I am wrong in understanding, or find statements don't put load on servers.

How does mongoDB handle select Or read operations?

I badly understand this.
Thanks in advance for responding

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "set up 2 shard servers"?  Do you mean you configured a sharded cluster with two shards?  that implies you are accessing the cluster through mongos process - are you?

Comment: Yes I have already setup sharded cluster with two shards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to a mongoD or mongoS server via the shell (mongo), you won't be able to look at the queries happening on that server. The shell is mainly there to execute queries, configurate the database and check it's status.

`MongoS` is simply a router of the queries coming from the application.

To the see the individual queries you'll need to check the log files which are located on each server based on your [configuration](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration).

By default only slow queries (under 100ms) will be logged. So will need to enable the [Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling) to log all queries.

You can read this [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-mongodb-distribute-queries-among-shards) [pages](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-mongodb-distribute-queries-among-shards) for more info on Sharding.

Comment: Thank you Gian , The valuable Info you provided  on Profiling , this is what I was looking for .